# Caves for Unreal Engine - convenient workflow

Tags: terrain, maps, unreal, level-design, levels

I'm doing a caves for my terrain. I have 2 solution, but none are good enough
*Caves are just a simple shapes - later I'm going to improve*

**The problem is - to merge a landscape and a caves**
Solution I know are
• using UE's Landscape System
• and without

### **Single-mesh terrain**

Caves - via mesh boolean

[image]

+clean merge line
+simple workflow
-is not compatible with UE Landscape System

### **UE Landscape using Visibility Mask**

It also affects collision (is enterable hole)
Caves are sepatate mesh

[image] [image]

+UE Landscape System
-merge line are awful

**Overall, Lanscape System gives to much out of a box, so I can simply drop it, and switch to a simple mesh**

Seems only way for now - to fill a gaps with other meshes
Blend a landscape with a mesh - is also not a case. It just a visual blend. Mesh accurately placed on atop of Landscape

**So, let me know, if you have a solution/idea - how to nicely merge a Landscape with a cave mesh**